# Iterating a groupby datetime over several weeks

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I'm trying to group my data by a week that I predefined using to_datetime and timedelta. However, after copying my script a few times, I was hoping there was a way to iterate this process over multiple weeks. Is this something that can be done?

The data set that I'm working with lists sales out sales revenue and spending out by the day for each data source and its corresponding id.

Below is what I have so far but my knowledge of loops is pretty limited due to being self-taught.

Let me know if what I'm asking is feasible or if I have to continue to copy my code every week.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date


startdate = '2021-09-26'
enddate =  pd.to_datetime(startdate) + timedelta(days=6)


last7 = (df.date >= startdate) & (df.date <= enddate)
df = df.loc[last7,['datasource','id','revenue','spend']]

df.groupby(by=['datasource_name','id'],as_index=False).sum()
df['start_date'] = startdate
df['end_date'] = enddate
df
```

Comment: Can you share sample dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your issue correctly, you are basically trying to aggregate daily data into weekly. You can try following code

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

#Get weekend date for each date

df['week_end_date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x,freq='W').end_time.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
#Aggregate sales and revenue at weekly level

df_agg = df.groupby(['datasource_name','id','week_end_date']).agg({'revenue':'sum','spend':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

`df_agg` will have all your sales and revenue numbers aggregated by the weekend date for corresponding date.

Comment: Hi SAL, thank you for your help! I will give it a try today and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Thank you SAL, gave it a try, and the script works well. Do you have any advice on where to learn more about lambda functions and stringing functions?

Comment: you can use a function instead of a lamba if your code rules increase. lambda are anonymous functions, nothing more.

Comment: So the client came back and now wants the start of the week to be Sunday ie Sunday = 0 instead of Sunday = 6. Is there a way to change the lambda function to reflect a Sunday start date? I told them its likely not doable since Datetime is based off of internal time